# Trouble Unioning to a table in linq

Tags: c#, linq

My goal is to grab a sum or the Values column of the linq query `AboriginalLnVal` which has the following select statement:

```
select new { Loan = final.Key, Value = final.Sum(Created => Created.AppLoanAmount) }
```

Below I grab the Sum of the Values from the query, I make it to a single row linq table.
and Union it to the existing table of summary.

```
var sum = AboriginalLnVal.Sum(x => x.Value);  
var TargetValue = new { Section = "2.1.2 (a)", Activity = "$ Value of Closed Deals by Aboriginal", Result = sum };  
var TargetValueLinq = Enumerable.Repeat(TargetValue, 1);  
combineFunction = combineFunction.Union(TargetValueLinq);
```

error produce:

```
Error   2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not
contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 
'Telerik.Windows.Data.QueryableExtensions.Union(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.IQueryable)' 
has some invalid arguments
```

If I can possible get some guidance that would be great, I believe I have to convert sum to to make it compatible But Not entirely sure, Quite new to this. 
System.Linq has been called

Comment: What is the query used to generate `combineFunction`?

Comment: Are you `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: combineFunction is a query sorry not a table. I've been union values ontop of it, had the size of x,y,z. x is section, y is value, z is results.

Comment: Actually I dont know what it is, I've just been grabbing x,y,z and stacking it ontop of eachother into combineFunction

Comment: The fields of the anonymous types must match _exactly_ to do a `Union`.

Comment: I definitely agree, hence why i had a feeling it was the Type of the sum value.

Comment: Am I doing the sum correctly?